# Stripe Payment Intents With Django And Stripe.js

Tags: javascript, python, html, django, stripe-payments

Problems:

Video: https://streamable.com/797e5

1) Submitting the Stripe.js form with a card that requires authentication (such as 4000002760003184 or pm_card_authenticationRequired) causes the 3D secure popup to appear but the the customer cannot do anything because the page refreshes automatically after clicking submit meaning the customer cannot properly authenticate in time. Need some way to slow this process down by having the customer finish authenticating first.

2) Not sure how to replace "pm_card_visa" with the card number that the user types into the Stripe.js form.

3) What should the form action be? Is {{checkout}} correct?

4) The except statement error message runs each time I try to submit a successful payment which is not desirable. There is also no code for showing the payment was successful.

5) Submitting the Stripe.js form does not store data in the Django database like the older Stripe tokens code does.

Note: Creating a subscription and a payment intent causes a successful charge for the subscription as well as the payment intent resulting in a customer getting double charged. I updated the code so that the subscription will be in trial thus avoiding the double charge.

Working Older Token Code:

```
https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/memberships/templates/memberships/membership_payment.html

https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/memberships/views.py

https://github.com/justdjango/video-membership/blob/master/static/js/checkout.js
```

Older Token Code Explanation:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu2PBUHMEew

Payment Intent Code Update Attempt:

```
https://pastebin.com/5wEkEjbq (stripe.js / checkout.js)

https://pastebin.com/7JXB4K4j (views.py)

https://pastebin.com/Kf0MeQ42 (membership_payment.html)
```

I want to take the older Stripe tokens code that works and update it with the new Payment Intent API while all the main functionality / result of the older token code remains the same but in an updated manner.

Result:

1) Customer types their credit card into the Stripe.js form

2) If the credit card is valid and non SCA, then process the card to Stripe and the Django database

3) If the credit card is valid but requires SCA, then authenticate the customer

4) Once the customer is authenticated then process the payment and send data to Stripe and the Django database.

5) Customer should have a Stripe subscription that pays monthly or yearly (depending on the plan setup in the Stripe dashboard).

6) The customer's payment intent should be confirmed / successful and the payment method (credit card) should be able to be re-used again for automatic monthly / yearly subscription payments.